# Float values in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to compare 2 varchar columns- col_1 & col_2,

```
col_1
A
A
A
1.0
2.0

col_2
A
A
A
1
2
```

I need to make sure that 1.0 & 1 are equal values, I can't convert them to integers as there could be valid values like 1.5...

Any tips?

Casting to float does not convert to 1.0, its still stored as 1,

```
  select cast(v as float)from 
  (select 1 as v) tb1
```

Comment: [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: float means floating point integer.  This means it will only display the decimal places that are required. `.0` is not required when the value is `1`.

Comment: Your problem is your incorrectly storing your information.  IN a varchar 1 and 1.0 are not the same thing, If you are micing numeric and character data inteh same column and you want to to do comparisions in another table, then the data can only work if you store it in the same format. If the numbers really are numbers to be compared, get them out of the varchar field and into a numeric field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your issue ?

```
Select CASE isnumeric(col_1)
    WHEN 1 THEN CAST(CAST(col_1 as DECIMAL(20,10)) as varchar(50))
    ELSE col_1
END
```

When you join with col_2 apply the same treatment to col_2. In your example 'A' will stay as 'A', and 1 will be '1.0000000000' in both columns.

Comment: Be careful with `ISNUMERIC`; it is true for monetary amounts like '$1.00'.

Comment: True. What's worth, things like '-' or ',' are also considered numeric by ISNUMERIC. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838224/catch-exception-with-isnumeric-in-sql-server/17838383#17838383) Gordon Linoff gives a more detailed answer to this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert to integer, but you can convert to float. If you still for some reason want to compare with decimal places do:

```
STR(col_1,LEN(col_1),1)
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(10),
    @b varchar(25)
SET @a = '123.00'
SET @b = '000123.000'

SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(@a,LEN(@a)+2,1))) = RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(@b,LEN(@b)+2,1))) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

Otherwise stick to the normal CONVERT/CAST, as this query returns true:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN CAST('1.0' AS FLOAT) = CAST('1' AS FLOAT) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 'YES'
FROM sys.tables
WHERE CAST(1 as float) = 1.0
```

The `CAST` statement can be used to temporarily cast your Integer to be a Float.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the numeric values to a float, and then back to a varchar, which will allow you to compare you varchar cols

Observe:

```
CREATE TABLE #table_1 ( col_1 varchar(10), col_2 varchar(10) )

INSERT INTO #table_1 
SELECT 'A', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT '1.0', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '1.2', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '2.0', '2' UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2', '2.1'UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2', '2.0' 

SELECT 
    col_1, 
    col_2,
    CASE WHEN 
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col_1) = 1 
        THEN CAST( CAST( col_1 AS FLOAT ) AS VARCHAR(10) )
        ELSE col_1 
        END 
        = 
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(col_2) = 1 
        THEN CAST( CAST( col_2 AS FLOAT ) AS VARCHAR(10) )
        ELSE col_2 
        END 
    THEN 'Equal' 
    ELSE 'Different' 
    END AS [comparison]
FROM #table_1

DROP TABLE #table_1
```