# Catch exception with isnumeric in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this possible values in a column

```
1
65
5 excellent
54
-1
-
.
```

If I use isnumeric with the last example I get 1, but when I try to convert to number I got an error. I want to use a try-catch in a function but I can't, how can I deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way, an even worse example is `'-.'`, which `isnumeric()` considers to be valid.

My advice is to look for at least one digit in the value as well.  Yucky, but:

```
isnumeric(val) and val like '%[0-9]%'
```

Note that `isnumeric()` also considers something in exponential notation to be valid.  So `'8e4'` will test as positive.  This may not be an issue for you, because it will convert to a valid value.  Such matches have caused a problem for me in the past, so I tend to use something like:

```
val not like '%[^0-9.]%' and val not like '%.%.%' and val like '%[0-9]%'
```

That is, it only has decimal points and digits.  And, it doesn't have two decimal points.  But, it only works for positive values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

> select case isnumeric('a') when 1 then convert(int,'a') else null end

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain your goal? Something like this could be useful:

```
SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC(col) 
    WHEN 1 THEN CAST(col as float)  -- or int, decimal, etc.
    ELSE NULL -- Or 0, -9999, or whatever value you want to use as "exception" value
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The TRY…CATCH construct cannot be used in a user-defined function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on SQL Server 2012, I recommend using TRY_CONVERT:

`select TRY_CONVERT(int, '.')` returns `NULL` instead of an error.